# Javascript addListner mousedown all events other than key up and down is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown

I have a listner on a table row like follows:

```
row.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
        var event = e || window.event;
        RowClick(this,false,event);
    });
```

and in my row click I have written as follows:

```
function RowClick(currenttr, lock,event) {

var key = event.keyCode || event.which;


    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        toggleRow(currenttr);

    }

    if (event.button === 0) {

        if (!event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey) {
            clearAll();
            toggleRow(currenttr);
        }

        if (event.shiftKey) {

            selectRowsBetweenIndexes([lastSelectedRow.rowIndex,currenttr.rowIndex])
        }
    }

    //up down arrows

    if((key == 38 || key == 40)&& !event.shiftKey && !event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey){
        alert("here");
    }


}
```

All the key events other than up down arrow key events are working.

```
if((key == 38 || key == 40)&& !event.shiftKey && !event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey){
            alert("here");
        }
```

**is not working**. Other keys like Shift , Control's actions are working!!

Answer (score 0):

The `mousedown` event does not includes data on regular keys which have been down when the event has occurred. The event only contains data on a spacial mask keys: `ctrl`, `shift`, `alt` and `meta`.

The event does not contains `keyCode` key, so you would always get `undefined` and the `which` key is dependent on the type of the click (left button: 1, right button: 3).

So after you run this code:

```
var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
```

`key` will always be equal to `event.which` so it never has the value 38 or 40.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) for which properties does the `mousedown` event contains.

---

A possible solution is to track the keys that are currently down:

```
var keysDown = [];

document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
   keysDown.push(e.keyCode || e.which);
}

document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
    var index = keysDown.indexOf(e.keyCode || e.which);
    if (index > -1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

and in your `RowClick` function:

```
if((keysDown.indexOf(38) > -1 || keysDown.indexOf(40) > -1) && !event.shiftKey && !event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey){
    alert("here");
}
```

You can also use boolean flag which indicates if the keys you want are down, instead of an array of all the keys which are down.